# ¿Por qué $_FILES no recibe ningún dato?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario donde quiero subir fotos a la base de datos, obtengo los datos con `formData` y los paso a php, pero luego del lado del servidor me aparece `$_FILES` vacío.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

  $('.contBtn').on('click','#publicar',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var formDatos = new FormData();
    var imagen = $('#formCrear').children('form').find('input[type="file"]').get(0).files;
    formDatos.append('archivo',imagen[0]);

     $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: datos,formDatos,
     }).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
     });

  });

</script>
```

De esta forma tomo los datos del `input="file"` con `formData` y los mando por AJAX a PHP junto con otros datos contenidos en un array llamado `datos`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['datos']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

function validar_imagen() {
  if (($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"] == "image/png")) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'])) {
        //more code here...
        echo "images/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
  } else {
      echo 0;
  }
}

echo validar_imagen();

}
?>
```

Este es la parte donde se envían los datos a PHP y trabajo con ellos. Solo coloqué la función que trabaja con la imagen.

Me arroja este error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo

Hice un `print_r($_FILES)` para ver qué contenía y me aparece un array vacío. No tengo idea de por qué.

Nota 1: No he trabajado antes guardando imagenes o archivos ni utilizando `formData`, quizá me esté equivocando al mandar esos datos con AJAX por falta de conocimiento.

Nota 2: los datos del `input="file"` se toman correctamente desde JQuery, los mostré en consola para probar y no hay problema con eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada recomendaría que el form lo pasaras completo, así evitarás que algún dato se pierda (solo es mi recomendación).

Para resolver el problema que estás teniendo, te mostraré cómo enviando el form completo y especificando algunas directivas de ajax vas a poder enviar correctamente archivos con ajax a php.

Primero tienes que establecer un `contentType`, `cache` y un `processData`. Puedes encontrar toda la información sobre cómo funciona técnicamente [aquí](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Es importante que envíes estos parámetros para que el formulario pueda llegar al servidor con las mismas características de hacerlo de la manera tradicional (ya que ahora lo estamos haciendo con ajax).

Vas a modificar tu petición a algo así:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    processData:false,  
    data: new FormData($('#formCrear')[0]),
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Nota cómo estamos incluso factorizando código enviando el formulario usando `new FormData($('#formCrear')[0])`. También debes asegurarte que tu `<input>` de tipo files tenga en su atributo `name` el valor de `archivo`, es decir, algo así como `<input type="file" name="archivo">`.

Ahora bien, es muy importante que si tu archivo destino se llama `miarchivo.php` (esta url por lo que veo la guardas en la variable `url`) exista y pueda ser encontrada por el servidor.

Suponiendo que lo anterior ya lo tengas resuelto, lo que ahora queda es editar ese archivo `php` que ya dijimos que se llama (por ponerle un nombre) `miarchivo.php`

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES["archivo"]);
```

Cuando veas la respuesta del servidor, podrás notar que ahora ya tienes llena la variable reservada $_FILES y con ello ya puedes proceder a terminar tu proceso.

Entonces, en resumen, tu error es no enviar los parámetros que le hacen falta a ajax y así enviar el formulario de manera correcta, es por eso que al llegar a tu servidor llega vacío. En algunas versiones anteriores de jQuery se regresa una excepción al no enviar los parámetros necesarios y enviar los datos como `new FormData`. En tu caso no viste esa excepción (quizá por la versión de jQuery) pero sin embargo en el servidor el contenido de la variable $_FILES llegaba vacía.

Es importante aclarar que en tu archivo php vas a tener acceso tanto  lo que se haya enviado por $_POST como por $_FILES de manera ordinaria.

Permíteme saber si esta respuesta te fue útil y si te ayudó a resolver tu problema

Saludos.

Comment: Fernando, gracias por la información! me di cuenta que debía declarar las directivas en AJAX que dijiste, pero también tengo que enviar los datos del `input="file"` solos, no como coloqué en el post (`data: datos,formDatos`). Ahora, cómo hago para pasar todos los datos de mi `form` con `formData`? ya que recojo unos datos de otros elementos que no son `input`

Comment: Había pensado pasar los datos que puedo tomar con `formData` y luego pasar los otros en otra petición AJAX a la misma url, pero no sé si sea la mejor opción

Comment: @KdisellQ Utiliza input de tipo hidden y esos los podrás trabajar del lado del servidor ya que al usar new FormData envías todos los parámetros incluyendo el file